flutter widget creation that takes external values
  The value variable is a constantly updated value. I want to constantly listen to this        

 variable and  redraw my button.But I couldn't do this. Can you help me? What I want to do is    this. I want to listen to value continuously. When there is a change, I want to change the button color or name accordingly. And I will draw the widget again.but I couldn't do it the way I wanted. I will use like 100 of these widgets. I want it to be a dynamic button.If you have another suggestion, you can show it to me. I want to write easy and robust code.

enter image description hereenter image description here
How should I proceed?Even though my value variable is coming in as true from outside, it is
coming in as false.

